# Python list doesn't transfer <a href> into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, beautifulsoup

Python novice here. I have scraped some data from BS4 and have the list below:

```
nfc_url = list(nfc_team_element2)
nfc_url

'[a href="/teams/teaminitial/year.htm">Team Name 1</a,
 a href="/teams/teaminitial/year.htm">Team Name 2</a]`
```

I want to extract each team name and the backend of the url ("/teams/phi/2022.htm"), then strip the url of the team code so it has the below columns in a data frame:

```
Team Name | Team Code
Team Name 1 | /teams/teaminitial/year.htm
```

However, when I tried to change the list into a dataframe, the below happens:

```
nfc_url_df = pd.DataFrame(nfc_url)
nfc_url_df

0
0   Team Name 1
1   Team Name 2
```

I am wondering how to fix this and why this is happening, since I would assume the data frame would contain the below for each line

```
a href="/teams/teaminitial/year.htm">Team Name 1</a>
```

Edit: minimum reproducible example:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2022/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

nfc_results = soup.find(id="div_NFC")

nfc_elements = nfc_results.find_all("tr")


nfc_team_element2 = nfc_results.find_all(
    "a"
)

nfc_url = list(nfc_team_element2)
nfc_url
```

Comment: That can't be the value of `nfc_url`. It begins with a quote, so it's a string, not a list.

Comment: Please post a [mre]. We need to see how you're setting `nfc_team_element2`.

Comment: If you're using Beautiful Soup to scrape the data, you can use `.string` to get the text, and `.href` to get the `href` attribute.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for your suggestions - minimal reproducible example below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to iterate through the find_all results to extract the values (team name and url code) needed for each matched tags. You can get only the text content of the tag using `.text` property and get the html attribute as dictionary key ie `<tag>['<attribute name>']`

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2022/"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

nfc_results = soup.find(id="div_NFC")

nfc_elements = nfc_results.find_all("tr")


nfc_team_element2 = nfc_results.find_all(
    "a"
)


nfc_url = []
nfc_teamnames = []
for tag in nfc_team_element2:
    nfc_teamnames.append(tag.string)
    nfc_url.append(tag['href'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Team Name': nfc_teamnames, 'Team Code': nfc_url})
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you @tax evader, that worked perfectly! Don't mean to bother you but do you have any suggested tutorials for learning more about BS4?

Comment: I think reading the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) should be the ideal way to learn it. Beautiful soup isn't too complicated compared to other web scraping tools to need a tutorial imo

Comment: Hasn't `.text` been replaced with `.string`? `.text` is no longer in the documentation.

Comment: @stwelhoelter Unlike many documentation sites, the BS4 documentation is very tutorial in nature. It has lots of examples.

Comment: Hmm I updated bs4 to 4.12.2 but `.text` still works. Yep I think `.string` should also work and is documented. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

There is a more direct way to extract the links/hrefs with `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2022/"

df_links = pd.read_html(URL, extract_links="body")
df = pd.concat(df_links)

df = df[['Tm']]
df[['Team', 'Link']] = df['Tm'].apply(pd.Series)
df = df.drop('Tm', axis=1)

# Drop rows where 'Link' column has None
df_cleaned = df.dropna(subset=['Link'])

# Remove any non-letter or number characters from the 'Team' values
df_cleaned['Team'] = df_cleaned['Team'].str.replace(r'[^A-Za-z0-9 ]', '', regex=True)
```